# Magento 2: Pass store ID to fileuploader of UI component

Tags: magento2.3.3

I have added a file uploader in the admin UI component form.

```
<field name="icon">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">FaqGroup</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Group Image</item>
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
        <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/image-preview</item>
        <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
        <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="routename/option/upload"/>
        </item>
    </item>
    </argument>
</field>
<field name="store_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\Collection</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">personalize_color</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

I have also store Id selection in this form. When I upload an image I need to save it to the selected store id folder. How can I pass the selected store ID to the file upload controller.

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: How you currently added store selection on this form?

Comment: I updated the question. I'm not getting selected store in routename/option/upload. Which is ajax request for file upload. I need to get store id here then move image to the folder/path/path/store_1

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add another field mentioning all stores in the dropdown and let the user select one of the stores and just access the store selected in the controller. You can use following to add the field;

```
<field name="storeviews">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

The data will be available in `storeviews` parameter in the controller's post or get whatever you are using to send the data.

Comment: I updated the question. I'm not getting selected store in routename/option/upload. Which is ajax request for file upload. I need to get store id here then move image to the folder/path/path/store_1